# How to trigger forcefully change detection without changing any input value or reference in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

In My code there is one scenario where neither i want to change input value nor want to change reference of input of child component, but still want to trigger change detection forcefully from parent to child component.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: first of all, why do you need to force change detection if nothing changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ChangeDetectorRef` provider to force it. In your constructor:

```
...
public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
...
```

Then, you can use `this.cdr.detectChanges()` to detect changes.

Docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: yes i have tried this, but this will only trigger the change detection when you will change input of child component. Without changing input(value or reference) change detection will not trigger.

Comment: are you using the OnPush change detection strategy? if so, you may need to change back to default change detection.

Comment: No, I am not using OnPush change detection strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using markForCheck() method of ChangeDetectorRef as this will ensure that component is checked for changes even if none of the triggers have occurred.